# Rendering scene background in only some frames of an animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes, optimization

Is there any way to render a specific scene, say the background, during only the second half of an animation while the foreground renders the entire time? For example in a 100 frame clip could I get the foreground rendering for all 100 frames but have the background only render out for frames 60-100? I'm using cycles render.

Comment: Do you have a reason to render the background and the foreground at the same time? If not, just render them separately and composite them together later.

Comment: That’s true, but I was just thinking to save time and learn a bit if there was a way to do it automatically. But that is what I will do if there isn’t another option

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the renderability of the objects that are "background", pressing "I" while hoovering on the camera icon of an object or an entire collection.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any method to do this currently, but you could just render them both in different passes and then use the compositor to create the final result.